# Can we test Android Auto purely in emulators (2023)?

Tags: android, android-auto

This is the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38000649/can-we-test-android-auto-in-emulators-without-real-device) from 2016 (where the answer was basically: 'No'), but Android Auto since 2019 works very differently than it did 2016, so i think it is ok to ask again:

Android Auto basically gives you the ability to project app content to a car's head unit, and work with the input the user generates there.
The DHU (Desktop Head Unit) is an emulator that lets a desktop computer emulate the behavior of a real head unit (for instance translating the workings of a physical dial to keyboard shortcuts, getting fake audio input from .wav files, etc) - [The material that i read](https://developer.android.com/training/cars/testing#test-auto) always assumes that you plug a phone with your app into the computer running the DHU. I would like to have it all on one computer - is it possible to connect a virtualized phone, running the app under test on the same computer as the DHU?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to have a purely emulator-based android-auto env. It was... somehow painful but it worked.

In order:

- I installed desktop head unit emulator, latest available version was 2.0. `sdkmanager 'extras;google;auto'`
- I created an avd using the following system image: `system-images;android-33;google_apis_playstore;x86_64`.
- After launching that emulator I downloaded Android Auto apk from apkmirror. In particular, I used [version 9.8 for x86_64](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/android-auto/android-auto-9-8-6324-release/android-auto-9-8-632428-release-android-apk-download/download/?key=7ac98948892e5abcb69caff15ebe8bc1b70d8d5a):
- I installed that apk using `adb install PATH_TO_FILE`
- I enabled emulator's developer settings (by tapping several times on Settings -> About -> Build number)
- I went to Auto settings which are not available from apps menu. Under your emulator settings you have to go to "Connection Preferences" and then "Android Auto".
- Under those settings you need to enable Auto's developer mode by tapping several times on its System's version.
- Then you'll have available the option for starting the developer head unit settings, under the three dots menu on the top right of Android Auto's settings.
- After enabling that server you can follow the steps described on the "adb forwarding" part of [the official docs about this](https://developer.android.com/training/cars/testing#running-dhu), which are:
- forward adb ports: `adb forward tcp:5277 tcp:5277`
- Run dhu: `$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/extras/google/auto/desktop-head-unit`

Plus: if you are running linux and wayland you have to run dhu using xwayland, to do that you need to set an environmental variable before the previous step:

```
SDL_VIDEODRIVER=x11 $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/extras/google/auto/desktop-head-unit
```

Find below some print screens for helping finding things on emulator and the final victorius, glorious and spectacular dhu finally running:

[image: Android Auto settings]
[image: Auto's build version]
[image: Auto's three dot settings]
[image: Phone connected to DHU]
[image: DHU running!!!]